# Google App Maker (Training Hub Template) assets not appearing in html widget

Tags: google-app-maker

Thank you for any help ahead of time.
I am trying to use the Google Training Hub Template for my company. The only issue I cannot resolve myself is having the assets from a course appear in the html widget when a user starts the course. The asset is connected because it will appear in a separate window when the "open in new window" is clicked. The instructions say to publish the document first then use the url for embedding. I have tried the embed iframe and the publish link and get a 400 error. The html widget will show the editable slide file when I use the regular share link(not the publish share link). This widget works well with a youtube link as well. Please help with why this html widget might not display the published slide file. I would be willing to convert this to pdf as well but cannot get a pdf link to show either.

Answer (score 0):

This specific app template has been designed for the direct URL to your content to be inserted in the Content URL field. That field will not support an iFrame. In essence, it is already an iFrame. You only need to insert:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/ etc etc etc etc

Just the link in the iFrame will work!

Hope this helps